# How can I distinguish between a reset event triggered programmatically or from a reset button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form which includes an input with type `reset`.

I have an event listener (bound with jQuery) on the form's 'reset' event, however I want to bypass this when the form is reset programmatically (e.g. with `form.reset()`).

I can't see any immediate differences in the event object passed to the handler, is there another way that doesn't involve listening for clicks on the "reset" button?

Answer (score 2):

Use `Event.target`. It will not be set if the event fired programatically. See [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.target).

Comment: In the case of a "reset", event.target is always the form that is being submitted - regardless if it was triggered by a click on a button or programatically.

Comment: The event object in Gecko-based browsers is a bit more helpful, as it has an Event.originalEvent.explicitOriginalTarget property which is either the reset button or the form in programmatic resets

Answer (score -1):

```
$("input:reset").click(function(){

});
```

That way you catch all user clicks on reset but leave the reset action.

Comment: *is there another way that doesn't involve listening for clicks on the "reset" button?*

Comment: You could create a function to handle all resets and perform the logic there.

Comment: Click event isn't an option; what if I tab to that field and hit spacebar?

Comment: The _click_ even also fires if the button is activated via keyboard!

Comment: @WoutervanderHouven I am creating a function to handle resets, the logic is the problem - I can't see that you can distinguish between a reset from a reset button or `.reset()`